# Problemas al generar sumas en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando un script que me permita realizar operaciones para generar el costo total de los productos:

```
  var subtotal = 0;
  var ivaValor = 0;
  var total = 0;
  selected.forEach(function(dato) {
      var pretotal = dato.price * dato.quantity;
      parseFloat(pretotal)
      var total = total + pretotal;

  });
  console.log(total);
```

Pero total me lo regresa como Not a number (NaN), al momento no entiendo que pasa ya que total se está declarando int.

Nota: estoy iniciando en JS :)

Comment: Haz intentado inicializar total como float? es decir: var total = 0.0;

Comment: Prueba cambiando **var pretotal = dato.price * dato.quantity;** a **var pretotal = Number(dato.price) * Number(dato.quantity);**; desde luego la presente sugerencia es asumiendo que los datos corresponden a datos que pueden ser convertidos a número c/u. Comprueba que **pretotal** sea un número; no sea que sea *NaN* y por consiguiente total falla.

Comment: Ambas variables como pretotal y total resultan como int pero al momento de hacer el var total = total + pretotal; resulta como NaN y ya segui sus consejos, la verdad es que estoy bloqueado

Comment: Es mejor usar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) y/o  [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) para **todos** los valores que van a intervenir en el cáculo. Por ejemplo: **`var pretotal = parseInt(dato.price) * parseInt(dato.quantity);`** Si lo que recibes en `dato.price`  y en `dato.quantity` son del tipo float, entonces cambias `parseInt` por `parseFloat`: **`var pretotal = parseFloat(dato.price) * parseFloat(dato.quantity);`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No pude hacer que me mostrar NaN pero si pude notar que estas declarando 2 variables `total`, una fuera del foreach y otra dentro:

```
  //...
  var total = 0; // declaracion de variable total
  selected.forEach(function(dato) {
      var pretotal = dato.price * dato.quantity;
      parseFloat(pretotal)
      var total = total + pretotal; // otra vez declarando la variable total

  });
  console.log(total); // imprimes la variable total con el ambito global
```

Debido a la ultima linea deduzco que quieres sumar el valor de las operaciones `dato.price * dato.quantity;` a la variable `total` dentro del `foreach`. 
Elimina la declaracion de la variable total interna del `forEach` para que la operacion funcione:

```js
var selected = [
 {
  price : 44,
  quantity: 2
 },
 {
  price : 20,
  quantity: 1
 }
];

var subtotal = 0;
var ivaValor = 0;
var total = 0;
selected.forEach(function(dato) {
    var pretotal = dato.price * dato.quantity;
    parseFloat(pretotal)
    total = total + pretotal;

});
console.log(total);
```